# First word only appearing in a form text box

Tags: php, textbox

Yes, I am coding on New Year's eve. Anyway, I have what I think is a strange problem (strange enough to need help). The following code works (sort of). The echo on line 6 ($row["sitename"]) outputs a full name like "Huntington Park", BUT... the first textbox inside the form only shows "Huntington", not the second part of the name.
Included below is a snipped of the screen.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `siteinformation` 
            WHERE `id` = '".$sitedrop."'";
            echo $query;
    $results = $pdo->query($query);
        while ($row = $results->fetch()) { 
        echo $row["sitename"].'
            <form action="dummypage.php" method="post">
            <table width="526">
              <tr>
                <td width="520" align="right"><p>Site Name: 
                    <input type="text" name="sitename" value='.$row["sitename"].'>
                 </p>
                  <p>Program: 
                    <input type="text" name="program" value='.$row["program"].'>
                  </p>
                  <p>Phone: 
                    <input type="text" name="sitephone" value='.$row["sitephone"].'>
                  </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>';
        }
```

Comment: You sure this isn't a display issue - e.g. style or character limit of the input field?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code outputs:

```
<input type="text" name="sitename" value=Huntington Park>
```

and it should be:

```
<input type="text" name="sitename" value="Huntington Park">
```

Change:

```
    <input type="text" name="sitename" value='.$row["sitename"].'>
```

to:

```
    <input type="text" name="sitename" value="'.$row["sitename"].'">
```

Since the value is not in quotes - it picks only the first string!
You should do the same with the other inputs.

Comment: You don't have to escape the double quotes as the string is within single quotes. =o)

Comment: Ah... Cool - Thanks! Damn quotes again... I should have figured.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that using HEREDOC notation is useful.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
$results = $pdo->query($query);
$out = NULL;
while ($row = $results->fetch()) 
{ 
    $out. = <<<ENDOUT
    $row["sitename"]
    <form action="dummypage.php" method="post">
    <table width="526">
    <tr>
    <td width="520" align="right">
    <p>Site Name: 
    <input type="text" name="sitename" value="{$row["sitename"]}" />
    </p>
    <p>Program: 
    <input type="text" name="program" value="{$row["program"]}" />
    </p>
    <p>Phone: 
    <input type="text" name="sitephone" value="{$row["sitephone"]}" />
    </p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
ENDOUT;
}
echo $out;
```

Comment: Looks nice and clean. I'll check it out. I'm sure I am picking up bad habits as I'm teaching myself this as I go along. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<input type="text" name="sitename" value='.$row["sitename"].'>
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="sitename" value="'.$row["sitename"].'">
```